# How to force display of the window

Tags: swt

I have the follow code:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;

public class ProvaShow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ProvaShow window = new ProvaShow();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void open() throws InterruptedException {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Shell shell = new Shell();
        shell.setSize(450, 300);
        shell.setText("SWT Application");

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        shell.forceActive();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If is open another application (es. browser web), how do I can force to show to the window that I running?

Comment: You want to stay your window on top of all other applications? To make him modal..?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the window for 3 seconds and then close it, then replace `Thread.sleep(3000);` with

```
display.timerExec(3000, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        shell.dispose();
    }
});
```

and make the `shell` final...